# Can I put a line break in \pgftext?

Tags: tikz-pgf, line-breaking

Simple question: I'm making a picture with PGF (basic layer, not TikZ) and I would like to add some text using `\pgftext`. The problem is that any `\\` or `\newline` line breaks within the text are apparently ignored. Is there some way I can force a line break to appear?

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pgf}

\begin{document}
 \begin{pgfpicture}
  \pgftext{can haz line \\ break plz?}
  \pgftext[y = -20pt]{i made u a line \newline break but tex eated it}
 \end{pgfpicture}
 \end{document}
```

This is not mentioned in the manual at all, and the only other discussion I can find is [this post from comp.tex.pgf.user](http://www.digipedia.pl/usenet/thread/16718/471/) which doesn't actually include a solution, only the workaround of using a TikZ node with `[align=...]`. But, mostly for curiosity's sake, suppose using TikZ is off the table. Is it still possible to do line breaks? (I would think so, since TikZ itself must do it somehow)

Comment: could you put it in a `tabular` environment? something like `\begin{tabular}{c}i made u a line \\ break but tex eated it\end{tabular}`...

Comment: Or you could just wrap it in `\shortstack{...}` if it's not too complex. TikZ itself used a `minipage`, I think.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

egreg's solution or perhaps a minipage

```
\pgftext[y=-20pt]{\begin{minipage}{5cm}can haz line \\ break plz?\end{minipage}}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just a guess: `\pgftext` works with `\hbox`. So the answer might be

```
\pgftext{\vbox{\hbox{can haz line}\hbox{break plz?}}}
```

but probably

```
\pgftext{\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}can haz line\\break plz?\end{tabular}}
```

is handier (and can be wrapped up in a macro).